# pl/sql block to increment salary by 15% of employees. I can't get the 15% increment

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR cr_rohan IS
        SELECT *
        FROM   rohan
        WHERE  city='Mumbai'
        AND
        SET salary = (salary * 115)/100;

    name_rec rohan%rowtype;

BEGIN
    OPEN cr_rohan;

    LOOP
        FETCH cr_rohan INTO name_rec;

        dbms_output.put_line(name_rec.name||' '||name_rec.dept_no||' '||name_rec.job);

        exit WHEN cr_rohan%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cr_rohan;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

Without benefit of any error messages, it appears your cursor definition is malformed.

If it is your intent to increase all Mumbai salaries by 15% your cursor would need to look like `SELECT * FROM rohan WHERE city = 'Mumbai'`.

Hopefully, something in your table is a key to the individual.  In which case you would perform the salary update within your FETCH loop as:

```
UPDATE rohan SET salary = [adjusted salary] WHERE key = name_rec.key;
```

However if it is your intent to increase all Mumbai salaries by 15% (and not just certain individuals) a simple UPDATE would be more efficient.

```
UPDATE rohan SET salary = (salary * 1.15) WHERE city = 'Mumbai';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use an `UPDATE` statement and if you want to list the modified rows you can use a `RETURNING column BULK COLLECT INTO collection` clause:

```
DECLARE
  names   SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
  depts   SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST;
  jobs    SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
BEGIN
  UPDATE rohan
  SET   salary = salary * 1.15
  WHERE city   = 'Mumbai'
  RETURNING name, dept_no, job
  BULK COLLECT INTO names, depts, jobs;
  
  FOR i IN 1 .. names.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( names(i) || ' ' || depts(i) || ' ' || jobs(i) );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to change any value in the table you have to use UPDATE instead of select. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10007.htm

Secondly, increasing by 15% means that you should add 15% of the current value to this value so it should be salary + 0.15*salary.

Finally, if you necessarily need to use PL/SQL block and loop. You should extract data using cursor or cursor for update then update salary in the loop, but frankly speaking it can be done in one line of code with UPDATE statement.

Comment: Secondly,  what is the difference between   `salary + 0.15*salary` and `(salary * 115)/100` ?

Comment: yup. you are right. I don't know what I was thinking of:)

Comment: Indeed, what is the difference between `(salary * 115)/100`, `salary * 115/100` and `salary * 1.15`? Personal preference I suppose but I prefer the simplest one.